# How can I make my jQuery codes more efficient?

Tags: jquery, function

I have the following jquery lines to count how many characters left on 4 different textarea fields:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $('#submission1').keyup(function() {
        var len = this.value.length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
        }
        $('#countCharacters1').text(1500 - len);
    });
    $('#submission2').keyup(function() {
        var len = this.value.length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
        }
        $('#countCharacters2').text(1500 - len);
    });
    $('#submission3').keyup(function() {
        var len = this.value.length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
        }
        $('#countCharacters3').text(1500 - len);
    });
    $('#submission4').keyup(function() {
        var len = this.value.length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
        }
        $('#countCharacters4').text(1500 - len);
    });
});
```

They work fine, but is there anyway to make them more efficient?

Cheers.

Comment: @SalmanA I took it to mean avoiding duplicated code.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes that would be to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, learned a few things there. Great help as always.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#submission1, #submission2, #submission3, #submission4').keyup(function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        if (len > 1500) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 1500));
        }
        $('#countCharacters' + $(this).attr('id').slice(-1)).text(1500 - len);
    }).keyup();
});
```

It can be simplified even more if you have a common class across your textareas, and we can avoid the id manipulation at the end of you give us a bit more details about the HTML layout - specifically how the #countCharacters elements are positioned in the DOM relative to the textareas.

An ideal solution would look something like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.editors').keyup(function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        if (len > 1500) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 1500));
        }
        $(this).next('.count').text(1500 - len);
    }).keyup();
});
```

This requires your textareas to have the `editors` class, and the count elements to have the `count` class and be positioned immediately after their respective textareas. A similar solution could be designed regardless of where the count elements are actually positioned though.

### Update

Based on this HTML, which you included in a comment:

```
<div class="field">
    <textarea name="submission1" class="editors" id="submission1" style="width: 680px"><?=$writtenSubmission1;?></textarea>
</div>
<p align="right">
    <span id="countCharacters1" class="count" style="font-weight:bold">1500</span>
    characters left
</p>
```

The `text()` line needs to change to this:

```
$(this).closest('.field').next().find('.count').text(1500 - len);
```

Basically, you're just traversing the DOM tree to get from the textarea element `$(this)` to the correct `.count` element. See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) for more information on functions that are available to help you move around the DOM.

I also made one more minor change above, to trigger the `keyup()` function immediately after binding the event handler to it, in order to show the correct count as soon as the page loads.

You can see a working version with your HTML in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tXArh/

Comment: Your second solution seems to be much simpler than the first one, but I couldn't make it to work. 
My html code:
<div class="field">
 <textarea name="submission1" class="editors" id="submission1" style="width: 680px"><?=$writtenSubmission1;?></textarea>
</div>
<p align="right"><span id="countCharacters1" class="count" style="font-weight:bold">1500</span> characters left</p>

Comment: @ jcsanyi Thank you for the explanation. Works perfectly. Learned more advanced stuff today. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

```
function countChars(index){
    var len = this.value.length;
    if (len >=1500) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
    }
    $('#countCharacters' + index).text(1500 - len);
}

$(window).load(function () {

    $('#submission1').keyup(function() {
        countChars.call(this, 1);
    });
    $('#submission2').keyup(function() {
        countChars.call(this, 2);
    });
    $('#submission3').keyup(function() {
        countChars.call(this, 3);
    });
    $('#submission4').keyup(function() {
        countChars.call(this, 4);
    });
});
```

Comment: @mohkan thanks for this. Works like a charm. More efficient than my original code.

Answer (score 1):

give class 'text-area' to each textarea then,

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $('.text-area').keyup(function() {
        var index = $(this).attr('alt');
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 1500));
        }
        $('#countCharacters' + index).text(1500 - len);
    });

});
```

give first textareas alt='1' and like wise

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the textareas a common css class (e.g. `submission`). Then use data-attributes on the textareas, to specify the max. number of characters allowed and the id of the element, which shows the number of remaining characters:

```
<textarea id="submission1"
  class="submission"
  data-maxchars="1500"
  data-remaining="remaining1">
</textarea>
<span id="remaining1"></span> chars left.
```

This allows you to simplify and generalize your jquery code like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.submission').keyup(function() {
        var $ta = $(this);
        var max = $ta.data('maxchars');
        var len = $ta.val().length;
        if (len >= max) {
            $ta.val($ta.val().substring(0, max));
            len = max;
        }
        $('#' + $(this).data('remaining')).text(max - len);
    });
});
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgmqz/3/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the JQuery each function :

```
     $.each( [1,2,3,4], function(i, n){  // i = position, n = value
       $('#submission'+n).keyup(function() {
        var len = this.value.length;
        if (len >=1500) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 1500);
        }
        $('#countCharacters'+n).text(1500 - len);
       });
    });
```